# Showing An "In Stock" Image For All Products Which are In Stock On Our Zencart Store

Tags: php, image, status

Trying to get an "In Stock" image to show for all of our products which are currently in stock on our Zencart store.

By default the store only shows and "out of stock" image for products, when there are out of stock.

The code that we are trying to tweak to adapt the "In Stock" image status is below:

```
$lc_button = '';
            if (zen_requires_attribute_selection($record['products_id']) || PRODUCT_LIST_PRICE_BUY_NOW == '0') {
                // more info in place of buy now
                $lc_button = $more_info_button;
            } else {
                if (PRODUCT_LISTING_MULTIPLE_ADD_TO_CART != 0) {
                    if (
                        // not a hide qty box product
                        $record['products_qty_box_status'] != 0 &&
                        // product type can be added to cart
                        zen_get_products_allow_add_to_cart($record['products_id']) != 'N'
                        &&
                        // product is not call for price
                        $record['product_is_call'] == 0
                        &&
                        // product is in stock or customers may add it to cart anyway
                        ($listing_quantity > 0 || SHOW_PRODUCTS_SOLD_OUT_IMAGE == 0)
                    ) {
                        $how_many++;
                    }
```

Any advice or help on adding some code for the "In Stock" image to show, would be appreciated!